# Is the more management tools for MySQL Workbench snippets

Tags: mysql-workbench

How can I reorder snippets in MySQL Workbench? Maybe is the plugin? 
Can I create additional snippets groups, like "My Snippets"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation titled [SQL Snippets tab](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-snippets.html) describes how to do this. It lists text files, such as "User Snippets.txt", that you can edit. To add a new group, add an additional text file in that directory, such as "Great Snippets.txt" to add a group titled "Great Snippets".

As for reordering the groups, I'm not yet sure.

Comment: Actually, I was looking for more elegant solution, like manage snippets through MySQL Workbench user interface, but your answer actually helps me alot. Thank You.